# Failure - Authentication is required to pull public docker images from Dockerhub registry

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile

I am using Jenkins Custom Build Environment Plugin (1.6.5) to build images from a Dockerfile inside the slave container checked in along with the source code.
Slaves running on `Docker version 1.9.1, build ab77bde/1.9.1`
[image]

My Dockerfile is as below which is able to pull from official ubuntu image but fails to pull from official node.js image -

```
FROM node:boron
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

On Jenkins job execution I get below failure -

```
    $ docker build --file /data/name-jenkins/workspace/TestJobs/BuildFromSCM/Dockerfile /data/name-jenkins/workspace/TestJobs/BuildFromSCM
Sending build context to Docker daemon 149.5 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 149.5 kB

Step 1 : FROM node:boron
Trying to pull repository registry.access.redhat.com/node ... failed
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/node ... failed
Authentication is required.
FATAL: Failed to build docker image from project Dockerfile
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build docker image from project Dockerfile
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.Docker.buildImage(Docker.java:134)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.DockerfileImageSelector.prepareDockerImage(DockerfileImageSelector.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.DockerBuildWrapper.setUp(DockerBuildWrapper.java:169)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:156)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am able to build the Docker image on my local machine though. I confirmed that the Jenkins slave user has sudo permissions.

Comment: How are you able to define 2 base images in 1 file? Afaik, that is not possible. Looks like a [bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14412#issuecomment-118995461).

Comment: @hurturk - I am able to replicate the issue with a single base image - FROM node:boron as well. Updated the original Dockerfile in my question.

Comment: I doubt if docker is outdated, `docker -v` what would be your version?

Comment: @hurturk - I am on Docker version 1.9.1, build ab77bde/1.9.1

Comment: Just worth trying to fix local time on slave nodes: `sudo ntpdate time.nist.gov`, in past, several pull/auth issues were related to that.

Comment: Also good idea to see if you can ssh to slave and `docker pull node:boron` manually to see if problem is related to docker or jenkins. Make sure you `docker rmi node:boron` after the successful pull so you can continue to debug the problem in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue in `.docker/config.json` on my slave machine where I accidentally set my dockerhub credentials which caused in failure in pulling public images with a generic user I was using to build Jenkins job.

```
{
    "ServerURL": "https://index.docker.io/v1",
    "Username": "myusername",
    "Secret": "passw0rd1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need a certificate of the docker-hub, which is a `ca.crt` file put in:

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/
```